# Codeigniter error Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect: auth failed

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, bigdata, database

I am trying to connect to a mongodb database 'exam' using codeigniter mongodb library Codeigniter-mongo-library-master. I have created an user for this db using

```
db.createUser({ user: "root",
  pwd: "root",
  roles: [
    { role: "readWrite", db: "exam" },
   ]
}}
```

It was successful.

Then, when I tried to connect to this database in codeigniter using :

```
$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = FALSE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['port'] = '27017';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['username'] = 'root';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['password'] = 'root';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['database'] = 'exam';
```

I got an error as shown below:

> Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database 'exam' with username 'root': auth failed.

**I am using php version 5.5.12 and mongodb driver php_mongo-1.5.1-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll on Windows 7.**

Can I get some help in solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

try changing the value of this variable:

**$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = FALSE**

to

**$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = TRUE**

Answer (score 0):

Now open your controller or model file, where you need another database connection active and write below code in the constructor of the class.

```html
$this->load->library('mongo_db', array('activate'=>'newdb'),'mongo_db2');
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late reply. I didn't understand your answer. Can you please elaborate. You said that i need to use the above code if i want another connection to the database. But why would i need it? I already have a database 'exam' with user credentials.